# Download a csv file from gmail using python

Tags: python, csv, gmail

I tried different python scripts for download a CSV attachment from Gmail. But I could not able to get it.Is this possible. If it is possible which python script should I use? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the python `requests` package. Its easy to use and covers most usecases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. This is not my own work. I got some codes, combined them and modified to this code. However, finally, it worked.

```
print 'Proceeding'

import email
import getpass
import imaplib
import os
import sys

userName = 'yourgmail@gmail.com'
passwd = 'yourpassword'
directory = '/full/path/to/the/directory'


detach_dir = '.'
if 'DataFiles' not in os.listdir(detach_dir):
    os.mkdir('DataFiles')



try:
    imapSession = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    typ, accountDetails = imapSession.login(userName, passwd)
    if typ != 'OK':
        print 'Not able to sign in!'
        raise

    imapSession.select('[Gmail]/All Mail')
    typ, data = imapSession.search(None, 'ALL')
    if typ != 'OK':
        print 'Error searching Inbox.'
        raise


    for msgId in data[0].split():
        typ, messageParts = imapSession.fetch(msgId, '(RFC822)')
        if typ != 'OK':
            print 'Error fetching mail.'
            raise

        emailBody = messageParts[0][1]
        mail = email.message_from_string(emailBody)
        for part in mail.walk():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                continue
            if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                continue
            fileName = part.get_filename()

            if bool(fileName):
                filePath = os.path.join(detach_dir, 'DataFiles', fileName)
                if not os.path.isfile(filePath) :
                    print fileName
                    fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
                    fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                    fp.close()
    imapSession.close()
    imapSession.logout()

    print 'Done'


except :
    print 'Not able to download all attachments.'
```

Comment: For me this fails because `emailBody` is of type `bytes` not `str`. Adding `emailBody = emailBody.decode('utf-8')` fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

## TL;DR

- I've put together [a Github repo](https://github.com/robertdavidwest/google_api) that makes getting CSV data from Gmail as simple as:

  ```
  from gmail import *
  service = get_gmail_service()

  # get all attachments from e-mails containing 'test'
  search_query = "test"
  service = get_gmail_service()
  csv_dfs = query_for_csv_attachments(service, search_query)
  print(csv_dfs)
  ```
- Follow the instructions in the `README` and feel free to contribute!

## THE LONG ANSWER (directly using `google-api-python-client` and `oauth2client`)

- [Follow this link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) and click the button: "ENABLE THE GMAIL API". After the setup you will download a file called `credentials.json`.
- Install the needed Python packages:

  ```
  pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client oauth2client
  ```
- The following code will allow you to connect to your Gmail account via Python:

  ```
  from googleapiclient.discovery import build
  from httplib2 import Http
  from oauth2client import file, client, tools

  GMAIL_CREDENTIALS_PATH = 'credentials.json' # downloaded
  GMAIL_TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json' # this will be created

  store = file.Storage(GMAIL_TOKEN_PATH)
  creds = store.get()
  if not creds or creds.invalid:
      flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(GMAIL_CREDENTIALS_PATH, SCOPES)
      creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
  service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
  ```
- With this service you can read your emails and any attachments.
- First you can query your e-mails with a search string to find the e-mail id's that have the attachments:

  ```
  search_query = "ABCD"
  result = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=search_query).execute()
  msgs = results['messages']
  msg_ids = [msg['id'] for msg in msgs]
  ```
- For each `messageId` you can find the associated attachments in the email.
- This part is a little messy so bear with me. First we obtain a list of "attachment parts" (and attachment filenames). These are components of the email that contain attachments:

  ```
  messageId = 'XYZ'
  msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=messageId).execute()
  parts = msg.get('payload').get('parts')
  all_parts = []
  for p in parts:
      if p.get('parts'):
          all_parts.extend(p.get('parts'))
      else:
          all_parts.append(p)

  att_parts = [p for p in all_parts if p['mimeType']=='text/csv']
  filenames = [p['filename'] for p in att_parts]
  ```
- Now we can obtain the attached CSV from each part:

  ```
  messageId = 'XYZ'
  data = part['body'].get('data')
  attachmentId = part['body'].get('attachmentId')
  if not data:
      att = service.users().messages().attachments().get(
              userId='me', id=attachmentId, messageId=messageId).execute()
      data = att['data']
  ```
- Now you have the CSV data but it's in an encoded format, so we change the encoding and convert the result into a Pandas dataframe:

  ```
  import base64
  import pandas as pd
  from StringIO import StringIO
  str_csv  = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data.encode('UTF-8'))
  df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(str_csv))
  ```
- That's it! you have a Pandas dataframe with the contents of the CSV attachment. You can work with this dataframe or write it to disk with `pd.DataFrame.to_csv` if you simply want to download it. You can use the list of `filenames` obtained earlier if you want to preserve the filename.

Comment: Note this doesn't work with python 3 due to differences in bytes constructor

Comment: Can use `BytesIO` instead with Python 3

Answer (score 1):

An up to date answer has been provided at [Download attachment from mail using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61368192/3491991)

> ```
> import os
> from imbox import Imbox # pip install imbox
> import traceback
>
> # enable less secure apps on your google account
> # https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
>
> host = "imap.gmail.com"
> username = "username"
> password = 'password'
> download_folder = "/path/to/download/folder"
>
> if not os.path.isdir(download_folder):
>     os.makedirs(download_folder, exist_ok=True)
>
> mail = Imbox(host, username=username, password=password, ssl=True, ssl_context=None, starttls=False)
> messages = mail.messages() # defaults to inbox
>
> for (uid, message) in messages:
>     mail.mark_seen(uid) # optional, mark message as read
>
>     for idx, attachment in enumerate(message.attachments):
>         try:
>             att_fn = attachment.get('filename')
>             download_path = f"{download_folder}/{att_fn}"
>             print(download_path)
>             with open(download_path, "wb") as fp:
>                 fp.write(attachment.get('content').read())
>         except:
>             pass
>             print(traceback.print_exc())
>
> mail.logout()
>
>
> """
> Available Message filters: 
>
> # Gets all messages from the inbox
> messages = mail.messages()
>
> # Unread messages
> messages = mail.messages(unread=True)
>
> # Flagged messages
> messages = mail.messages(flagged=True)
>
> # Un-flagged messages
> messages = mail.messages(unflagged=True)
>
> # Flagged messages
> messages = mail.messages(flagged=True)
>
> # Un-flagged messages
> messages = mail.messages(unflagged=True)
>
> # Messages sent FROM
> messages = mail.messages(sent_from='sender@example.org')
>
> # Messages sent TO
> messages = mail.messages(sent_to='receiver@example.org')
>
> # Messages received before specific date
> messages = mail.messages(date__lt=datetime.date(2018, 7, 31))
>
> # Messages received after specific date
> messages = mail.messages(date__gt=datetime.date(2018, 7, 30))
>
> # Messages received on a specific date
> messages = mail.messages(date__on=datetime.date(2018, 7, 30))
>
> # Messages whose subjects contain a string
> messages = mail.messages(subject='Christmas')
>
> # Messages from a specific folder
> messages = mail.messages(folder='Social')
> """
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
from imap_tools import MailBox

# get all .csv attachments from INBOX and save them to files
with MailBox('imap.my.ru').login('acc', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch():
        for att in msg.attachments:
            if att.filename.lower().endswith('.csv'):
                with open('C:/1/{}'.format(att.filename), 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(att.payload)
```

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools