# Python script downloading gmail attachment automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail-api

i want a python script to download automatic periodically (like every hour) gmail attachment which is a .jpg format i tried this code but it is not working.

> ```
> def get_csv_or_xl_attachments_from_msg_id(service, messageId):
>     """returns a dict of all CSV attachments as pd.DataFrames
>     in the email associated with `messageId`. The keys for the
>     dictionary are the csv filenames"""
>     msg = service.messages().get(userId='me', id=messageId).execute()
>     msg_parts = msg.get('payload').get('parts')
>     headers = msg.get('payload').get('headers')
>     subject = [h['value'] for h in headers if h['name']=='Subject'][0]
>     if not msg_parts:
>         return []
>     msg_parts = _flatten_nested_email_parts(msg_parts)
>     att_parts = [p for p in msg_parts if p['mimeType'] in [
>             CSV_MIME_TYPE, XLSX_MIME_TYPE]]
>     types = [mime_type_to_dtype(p['mimeType']) for p in att_parts]
>     filenames = [p['filename'] for p in att_parts]
>     datas = [_get_attachment_from_part(service, messageId, p) for p in att_parts]
>     dfs = [_convert_attachment_data_to_dataframe(d, t)
>             for d, t in zip(datas, types)]
>     return [{'emailsubject': subject, 'filename': f, 'data': d}
>             for f, d in zip(filenames, dfs)]
>
>
> def query_for_csv_or_xl_attachments(service, search_query):
>     message_ids = query_for_message_ids(service, search_query)
>     csvs = [] 
>     for msg_id in message_ids:
>         loop_csvs = get_csv_or_xl_attachments_from_msg_id(service, msg_id)
>         csvs.extend(loop_csvs)
>     return csvs
> ```

above code is returning blank list. even though I've mails with attachment.
could anyone help me in this?
below is URL for whole repository.
https://github.com/robertdavidwest/google_api

Comment: Try using this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41749236/download-a-csv-file-from-gmail-using-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a csv file from gmail using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41749236/download-a-csv-file-from-gmail-using-python)